# HERE Places (Search) API - Discrepancies between Category System Documentation and API Responses

Tags: here-api

I am using the **HERE Places (Search) API** and I need an exact documentation of the **Places Category System** including all Levels of Places Categories which can be part of the API responses.

**Problem of existing documentation of HERE Places Category System:** (described here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/place_categories/places-category-system.html)
Category System Documentation and API Responses do not exactly match, e.g.:

***1.Example:*** Documentation includes "Hospital or Health Care Facility"-Place Category --> API Response includes "Hospital" as Place Category

***2.Example:*** Documentation: Place Category "Bar or Pub" (ID: 200-2000-0011) --> API Response includes "Pub/Bar" as Place Category

**Question**: Is there any possibility to get the exact documentation of the current version of the Places Category Levels (exact naming!) included in the API responses?

Comment: Hi Ana, thanks for bringing it up, we will work with engineering team to review the docs. Meanwhile, to save your invaluable time please try to use the Geocoding and search API V7 (https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-api/code-discover-category.html) since the Place(search) is in maintenance.

Comment: I am interested in a place's category at different GPS positions (considering **all potential categories**, not only in a specific category like "hotel"). Therefore, I don't think the "Geocoding and search API V7" you had linked is suitable for that? In the documentation it says that "either q (e.g. hotel) or qq-parameter is required on this endpoint." [https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html]

Comment: Hi Ana, in this case then the browse would be a better option for you. For example: https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?at=42.35814,-71.05765 you can have more details here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-browse-brief.html

Answer (score 0):

To recap, for the use case that you are interested in a place's category at different GPS positions (considering all potential categories, not only in a specific category like "hotel") then the browse would be a better option for you.
For example: browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?at=42.35814,-71.05765

Further details can be found here: developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/…